# Sample Java code to simulate out of memory situation

Tags: java

I am basically a Weblogic admin and want to simulate out of memory situation through deploying a very simple Java code(war/ear file) in my Weblogic instance.

I have a very little knowledge about Java coding so can someone please provide me a sample code which I can easily pack as war and deploy?

Comment: Which memory? Heap? Stack? What have you thought so far that could work?

Comment: Start the web server with a ridiculously low max heap size? ;)

Comment: while i appreciate that this has so many upvotes, the OP made no effort on the question.

Comment: can one be a weblogic admin w/o any Java knowledge?

Comment: @MK. If so then I highly doubt SO is the place to ask.

Comment: To simulate out of memory just `throw new OutOfMemoryError();` if you want to actually run out of memory do `List l = new ArrayList(); while(l.add(new long[10000000]));`

Answer (score 20):

This should be enough:

```
long[][] ary = new long[Integer.MAX_VALUE][Integer.MAX_VALUE];
```

This will try to allocate 2^31 + 1 memory blocks, each of size 2^34 bytes.

Answer (score 8):

You can do `final long[] l = new long[Integer.MAX_VALUE];` It will allocate 16Gb - 8 bytes.

Or you can just `throw new OutOfMemoryError();`

Comment: Today's servers may just humor you with a block of 2^34 bytes :) But the second suggestion could be enough for most cases.

Comment: +1 For the second solution; can't get more direct/simple than that.

Comment: Just a callout ``throw new OutOfMemoryError();`` doesn't run HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError.

Answer (score 2):

To simulate the memory being consumed over time try:

```
List<long[]> list = new LinkedList<long[]>();
while (true) {
  list.add(new long[65536]); // an arbitrary number
  // sleep(1) perhaps?
}
```

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik thx Marko, I've been coding too much in C recently, apparently.